# How can I make python use more of my cpu?

Tags: python, optimization, resources, cpu, cpu-usage

I have a pretty performance-heavy python script that i'd like to speed up. 
Even though the process' priority is set to "realtime", it only uses 10% of one of 12 cores.
How can I make python use more and thus finish the tasks quicker?
Or is there a cap to prevent more than x calculations/actions per time?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: All Cores would be awesome, but even more usage of one would be nice
The Program is basically some nested loops, kinda like a bruteforce. It's one single function

Comment: depends on what sort of process you are trying to run, look into run-time optimization or/running your script within a virtual environment for less system dependencies and more of the bare minimum to run the script.

Comment: You might be able to look into threading your program to use multiple cores. https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Comment: Python threading will get you _at most_ one whole core of usage. If that's all you want, it's likely that asyncio is the right way to go (asynchronous programming, not threading) since you're probably hanging up on IO of some sort. If you want to use those 12 juicy cores, you need to look into multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is the broad field of "profiling" your code. You need to look at what's taking the most time (likely "wall" time) and dig deeper into what's causing that. Some likely options, but I'm just guessing since I don't have your code:

1. Waiting on disk or network is a common place where your code can get stuck. While profiling your code, see if you're reading/writing files or making network calls, and if so, consider writing your code in an asynchronous or parallel fashion (e.g. using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)) to allow either the single Python thread to work on multiple IO operations simultaneously or to have multiple Python processes blocking in parallel.
2. Are you sure it's 10% of 12 cores? CPU readouts often show a percentage of all cores, so it's possible that what you're seeing is ~10% of all the cores, which would be a full core. This is just a suggestion to double-check.
3. For many common tasks (numeric computation is a use case I'm particularly familiar with), there are Python libraries that implement common operations in low-level libraries and provide you high-level tools that use those libraries (e.g., Numpy). This is how most people get high-performance code in Python: by using the Python code to essentially script and bind together operations that are primarily implemented in low-level code by various libraries.

But as I'm sure you'll get told in comments and maybe even get this question flagged and closed for, you need to profile your code and figure out where the time is going and then dig deeper into that. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/).